# Onclick event for a button

Tags: html, button, onclick

I am creating a simple onclick event for a button. It's just not working. Below is what I wrote.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    rec(){
<?php
   $myfilename = "info.txt";
    if(file_exists($myfilename)){
      echo file_get_contents($myfilename);
    }
?>
    };
</script>
<button onclick="rec()">Click me</button>
```

Not sure, what wrong. I also commented entire php and just tried to echo hi, that also didn't work. 
Kindly request your advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out your javascript rather than putting PHP inside your javascript. For example you can try.

```
<?php
   $myfilename = "info.txt";
    if(file_exists($myfilename)){
       $file = file_get_contents($myfilename);
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'> function rec(){ console.log($file); console.log('This is JS being printed by PHP'); }</script>";
    }
?>
```

Please keep in mind you should declare your function with the function keyword and there is no way for us to tell what `$myfilename` returns without more information, but if you're just trying to print html inside of PHP this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's not reading function rec() onward, it's printing as it is into html page. I also tried calling that function from onclick event.